# Динамический шрифт в кнопках и TextField

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть вот такой вот интерфейс[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как мне сделать так что бы весь шрифт в кнопках, в TextField, и в таблице динамически изменялся при изменении размера окна.
Интерфейс написан с помощью JavaFX и SceneBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

По идее мы задаем общий размер, например:

```
.root {
  -fx-font-size: 15pt;
}
```

Далее каждому элементу устанавливаем специальный размер в `em`:

```
button {
      -fx-font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Далее вешаем событие на изменение окна приложения и изменяем базовый размер шрифта:

```
styleProperty().bind(Bindings.format("-fx-font-size: %.2fpt;", slider.valueProperty()));
```

По мотивам https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999605/how-can-i-change-the-base-font-size-in-javafx-8-modena-theme-that-would-cascade

Comment: А как мне все это провернуть учитывая что все у меня написано через SceneBuilder?